# python riotwatcher bad request for url

Tags: python, riot-games-api

I'm trying to access to the matchlist of a player from his puuid, but when i execute my code, i get an error... Why is this error happening? I have the right RiotApiKey, and the right player_puuid because when i execute the request from https://developer.riotgames.com/apis#match-v5/GET_getMatchIdsByPUUID it works and returns me the matchlist, i cant find why this simple task doesnt work.
Thanks for your help

My code:

```
from riotwatcher import LolWatcher
from settings import RiotKey,riotApiRegion,player_puuid

watcher = LolWatcher(RiotKey)
matches = watcher.match.matchlist_by_puuid(riotApiRegion,player_puuid)
```

Then i get this error :

```
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: https://euw1.api.riotgames.com/lol/match/v5/matches/by-puuid/RGAPI-a65424c1-2e67-44b0-97f5-0179453c3f5e/ids
```

Comment: You use the class definitions in your call, but I think that's not the intended usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new match_v5 uses a new type of region instead of "euw1" for exemple now it's "europe".

```py
old = ["na1", "euw1", "eun1", "kr", "br1", "jp1", "ru", "oc1", "tr1", "la1", "la2"]

new = ["europe", "asia", "americas"]
```

```py
from riotwatcher import LolWatcher
from settings import RiotKey,riotApiRegion,player_puuid

watcher = LolWatcher(RiotKey)
matches = watcher.match.matchlist_by_puuid("europe", player_puuid)
```